# Backbone, Jasmine - How to run tests in isolation, with no side effects?

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, phantomjs, jasmine-headless-webkit

I'm starting to use Jasmine(with PhantomJS) to test a Backbone app. The first problem I encountered is that state is persisted across tests. Hence tests see the DOM & data manipulations of each other, making them fragile.

Ideally, one would want each test to run in an isolated env and not effect other tests.

Not sure how people are dealing with this currently. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching this, I've found that its up to the developer to teardown, cleanup things properly.